# R - igraph: overlapping nodes with same y-axis

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I am plotting a food web ecological network with igraph and I am trying to avoid having my nodes to overlap.
The y-axis depends on the attributes of the nodes (i.e. the species trophic levels, varying between 1-3.52, no nodes between [1,2] by convention).

[image]

To do so, I calculate how many nodes there are within certain intervals of the y-axis range (1 to 4 with increments of 0.5).

If all nodes have the same size (defined by the user), I calculate the length of x-axis at each levels of y, as the sum of the size of the nodes (as if the nodes would be next to each other on a single axis):

`xl <- (n nodes + 1 + 2 ) * size`

I add 1 here since the nodes should be plotted from the certain of the nodes, so there is half a node on the left of the minima and right of the maxima of the x-axis. (The +2 is just to give a little space, and yes I know 1+2 =3 :) just to make the explanation easier).
I then calculate the break points on the x-axis calculating a sequence from half of the length I calculated above, centered around 0.

`seq(-xl/2, xl/2,length.out = nnodes)`

Doing so, each center of the nodes should be at a breakpoint on the x-axis with some distance between the nodes.

If the nodes have different sizes (defined by the user), I use the maximum size in the formula above so that I have enough space between each center of the nodes.

I combine the x-axis and y-axis coordinates as a matrix to use as my layout.

`coordsp <- cbind(xcoord, TLsp)`

I use rescale within the parameters of the plotting function.

```
plot(network, layout= coorsp,
       rescale=TRUE,...)
```

I still get some overlap.
I tried using rescale = FALSE, specifying the x-axis and y-axis limits (range of the coordinates in coordsp) but the graph end up looking weird or the plotting window turns completely white.
I think the issue when rescale = TRUE is that it rescales the coordinates but not the size of the nodes, so that if they are too big for a window [-1,1]x[-1,1], the nodes end up overlapping.

Any guess on how to avoid overlap?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered using `layout_with_sugiyama`? You can use the `layer` parameter to specify where nodes are vertically (the trophic level) and use `hgap` / `vgap` to ensure no overlap. Your layer number should be an integer though, and it's not clear to me if this is what you want, hence only a comment, no answer.